# Column is read differently by pyspark and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe exactly like below, read by pandas correctly:

The code I am using is very simple:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
hede = spark.read.parquet(r"C:/users/batuhan.engin/desktop/date=2021-04-01")
he = pd.read_parquet(path=r"C:/users/batuhan.engin/desktop/date=2021-04-01", engine='pyarrow')
```

The error is, pyspark reads the sales_revenue column incorrectly and I couldn't understand why.

```
he[he.product_id == 2461]:
    sales_type sales_channel  sales_quantity  sales_revenue  tax_amount currency  product_id  store_id
27     Regular     Wholesale             6.0     818.500000         NaN     None        2461       300
110    Regular     Wholesale             2.0     272.829987         NaN     None        2461        42
132    Regular     Wholesale            18.0    2475.540039         NaN     None        2461       314
```

But when I read it by Pyspark, sales_revenue column is not correct. Actually, I can't even think how pyspark come up with these values in sales_revenue column:

```
hede.filter("product_id == 2461").show()
+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|sales_type|sales_channel|sales_quantity|sales_revenue|tax_amount|currency|product_id|store_id|
+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
|   Regular|    Wholesale|           6.0|   -186969.84|      null|    null|      2461|     300|
|   Regular|    Wholesale|           2.0|       -444.8|      null|    null|      2461|      42|
|   Regular|    Wholesale|          18.0|      6553.92|      null|    null|      2461|     314|
+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+----------+--------+
```

Any idea? Might be versions or packages?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, can you add at least how you load the data in your both pandas and pyspark dataframes? to my knowledge, there is no obvious raison why this would happen if you read the data from the same source.

Comment: Can you share the actual data file (sample only)?